# 000Webhost is saying "You see this page because your website doesn't have "index.php" or "index.html" file in public_html folder."

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, public-html

I added an index.html page, but when I publish the site and go to my website: it says "Hooray, your free website has been started!

You see this page because your website doesn't have "index.php" or "index.html" file in public_html folder."

Comment: Are you sure you have the right file in the right location? A screenshot of that file in the public_html directory would be helpful to confirm.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file?  If so what does it contain?